# When content is empty, caret disappear in contenteditable

Tags: contenteditable, caret, focusin

When div[contenteditable] to empty(like $(this).html("")) then caret disappeared.

> Is it bug? Also I found some other solution. using setTimeout function. but It's not perfect solution for me. when I use many contenteditables division moving focus with tab key. then that solution is not working properly.
>
> > When I tested on Ubuntu 12.04,
> >
> > > in Firefox 20.0
> > >       Click event : caret disappeared,
> > >
> > > in Chrome 25.0
> > >       Focusin event : caret disappeared.

```
$(function() {
  $("#alpha").on("click", function(e) {
    console.log("click");
    $(this).children().html("");
  });
  $("#beta").on("focusin", function(e) {  
    console.log("focusin");
    $(this).html("");
  });     
});
```

You can test it [my fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ratsbomb/4yZ8K/)
Click yellow area, or other area.